# Error en compilación: undefined reference to 'crearNodo', pero sí la defino

Tags: c

Estoy realizando un programa de una lista enlazada en C, pero a la hora de probar mi función crear nodo me sale el error mencionado en el titulo, no logro visualizar el error.

Estos son mis archivos:

`lista.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "lista.h"

NODO* crearNodo(LIBRO *libro) {

    NODO* nodo = (NODO*) malloc(sizeof(NODO));
    strncpy(nodo->libro.titulo, libro->titulo, 50);
    strncpy(nodo->libro.autor, libro->autor, 50);
    strncpy(nodo->libro.isbn, libro->insb, 13);
    nodo->siguiente = NULL;

    return nodo;
}

void destruirNodo(NODO *nodo) {
    free(nodo);
}
```

`lista.h`

```
#include "libro.h"

typedef struct {
    LIBRO libro;
    struct NODO *siguente;
} NODO;

typedef struct {
    NODO *cabeza;
} LISTA;

NODO* crearNodo(LIBRO *libro);
void destruirNodo(NODO *nodo);
```

Y finalmente la función principal en donde realizo la prueba.
    #include 
    #include "lista.h"

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    printf("\n\n***** Test crear nodo *****\n\n");


    LIBRO libroNuevo = {"Programacion en c", "Deitel", "5677-567-6554-90"};
    NODO *nodoLibro;

    printf("titulo: %s autor: %s isbn %s", 
        libroNuevo.titulo, libroNuevo.autor, libroNuevo.isbn);

    nodoLibro = crearNodo(&libroNuevo);

    printf("titulo: %s autor: %s isbn %s", 
        nodoLibro->libro.titulo, nodoLibro->libro.autor, nodoLibro->libro.isbn);

    return 0;
}
```

Este es el error que la consola me muestra al compilar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando el compilador MinGW.

Comment: No estás compilando `lista.c`, por lo que no se crea el objeto `lista.o` que es el que contiene la definición que el compilador no está encontrando.

Comment: Sí ya lo agregue, pero me sale el mismo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al compilar el código donde viene el main no enlazas **lista.c**, que es la que declara la función *crearNodo()* intenta compilarlo con ambos.

> gcc .\testListaEnlazada.c (ruta de lista.c)\lista.c -o .\testListaEnlazada